# SSH and connection error

Tags: networking, server, ssh, netplan

I installed ubuntu server, I connect my computer to wifi and it works to download packages and other installations, however when I want to connect via SSH from another pc it doesn't work if I don't type the command "sudo netplan apply".  Also if I type "nmcli d" it tells me that the state is unavailable.  I need to connect via ssh to the computer without typing that command every time.  Also from windows I launched the ping command from cmd and it behaves the same way as the ssh command (ie it connects only after typing that command) help please.  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Install openssh

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install openssh-server
```

And then once it's installed, verify if it's running or not with

```
$ sudo systemctl status ssh
```

If the firewall is enabled on your Ubuntu installation, open the ssh port with

```
$ sudo ufw allow ssh
```

And then connect to your ssh server with:

```
$ ssh username@ip_address
```

Hope that helps.